# flutter in-app purchasing - works to remove adverts after app has been published?

Tags: flutter, in-app-purchase

I have an app written in flutter. I had to create 2 of them (one free (with adverts), one paid (without ads)), and I was looking into just having one free with in-app purchasing instead. 
But does this work if the app has already been published? or do I need to create a new App with In-App purchasing activated from the beginning?

If you see here:
https://github.com/flutter/plugins/blob/master/packages/in_app_purchase/example/README.md
It only gives me the instructions for creating this feature (in app purchasing) for new apps.